# How to only track .config files within subdirectories that are direct decendants from the working directory?

Tags: linux, git

I am trying to create a .gitignore file that should only track ".config" files that live within directories starting with "linux-" which are direct decendants of the working directory. I do not want to track any other files or subdirectories within the "linux-" directories. Eg. I do not want to track "/linux-4.2-blah/foo/.config", only "/linux-4.2-blah/.config" and only files with the exact name of ".config". I have tried the following and some other variants:

```
*
!/linux-*/
/linux-*/**
!/linux-*/.config
```

but when i run "sudo git add ." it also includes eg.

- "linux-4.19*/.clang-format"
- "linux-4.19*/.mailmap"

and a bunch of other files that I do not want

Anyone? Thanks!

Comment: Your quoted gitconfig works as expected for me. Manpage says "Git normally checks gitignore patterns from multiple sources", so check the other sources. Also don't use sudo if not necessary, and if necessary, check root user's gitignore definitions as well.

Comment: Ahh, yes you are right! It is of course because the subdirectories contains .gitignores as well that has higher precedence than the one in the root dir. I should probably take a different approach to this problem :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This .gitignore works fine for me, per the test below:

```
*
!linux-*
linux-*/**
!linux-*/.config
```

Tested with the following folder structure (.git folder omitted), git status shows `linux-*/.config` untracked and the rest ignored.

```
$ tree
.
├── .config
├── .git
│   └── …
├── .gitignore
├── README.md
├── folder
│   ├── .config
│   ├── .lorem
│   └── xy
├── linux-123
│   ├── .config
│   ├── .test
│   └── abc
└── test.txt

18 directories, 32 files

$ git status -uall --ignored
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        linux-123/.config

Ignored files:
  (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .config
        .gitignore
        folder/.config
        folder/xy
        linux-123/.test
        linux-123/abc
        test.txt
```

Comment: Yes, I can see now that the problem is .gitignores in subdirectories that overrules the one in the root directory. Didn't think about that. I will take a different approach to the problem. Thanks! :)